# Op-amp inverting summer

Tags: operational-amplifier

Why is an op-amp used in this summing circuit? Why can't I add the voltages without an op-amp? Current doesn't go into op-amp, so it goes through the Rf resistor either way.

[image: opamp adder]

Comment: This OpAmp topology adds voltages, not currents.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Actually, and fundamentally, this circuit *is* adding currents. The sum of the currents coming in from the left equals the current going out (through the feedback resistor) on the right. The resistors are used to convert voltages to currents.

Comment: @DaveTweed  I know.  Internally, it works with currents.  Externally, V1 through V4 are voltages.

Comment: For both discussion of op amp circuits -- including the "infinite-gain amplifier" theory (though he goes through that fairly fast) and real-world considerations involved in a very wide range of sample circuits, Jung's _IC Op Amp Cookbook_ was a darned good reference.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in total five voltage sources are connected through resistors to the common summing point (five current sources are connected to the summing point each of them consisting of a voltage source and resistor). I mean the op-amp output can be thought of as another voltage source. From this perspective, it is a kind of "input source"... but we take its voltage as an output quantity.

Comment: Figuratively speaking, the four input voltage sources "pull" up and down the summing point while the op-amp output voltage "source" restores its initial zero position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concept of the "op-amp virtual earth" is very important to understanding why the op-amp is used as a mixing/adding circuit: -

[image]

I've stolen the OP's picture and marked in red where the virtual earth is. Anything directly connected to the -input is called "virtual earth". OK that doesn't explain why so, here goes... If the voltage at the +input is 0V (aka earth or ground) then the voltage at the -input **HAS** to also be 0V.

This may seem a strange thing to say until you think about the general model of an op-amp - it has infinite gain (or at least very high gain) and, if the voltage difference between the two inputs were measurable, then the OP-AMP output would be end-stopped against one of the power rails.

But, this doesn't happen because of the process of negative feedback - the OP-AMP produces a voltage on its output that is just right (goldilocks value) for making the -input voltage (via Rf) exactly the same as +input. This is called negative feedback.

So how does this help the mixer - it means that all the inputs (V1 to V4) are connected to resistors that appear to go straight to 0V - this means the current thru each input resistor is NOT dependent on the other inputs and their currents - they all appear to go to ground or earthy or 0V.

This means it is a true mixer.

Comment: The virtual ground concept is very important for understanding the role of the op-amp in the circuit of inverting summer… but it is too difficult for beginners to understand it. They would understand how zero voltage appears at this place if they could imagine two things - first, where the current goes after leaving Rf and second, the fact that the op-amp output is connected in series to the resistor Rf and produces voltage  equal to the voltage drop across this resistor.

Answer (score 5):

> why i can't add voltage without opamp?

*You can*!

Remove the op-amp and the feedback resistor.  The voltage at the node connecting all four resistors is, by voltage division and superposition,

$$V_{sum} = V_1 \frac{R_2||R_3||R_4}{R_1 + R_2||R_3||R_4} + V_2 \frac{R_1||R_3||R_4}{R_2 + R_1||R_3||R_4} + V_3 \frac{R_1||R_2||R_4}{R_3 + R_1||R_2||R_4} + V_4 \frac{R_1||R_2||R_3}{R_4 + R_1||R_2||R_3}$$

But note that this result assumes an effective open-circuit for the load of our resistor only voltage summing circuit.  Assuming we *cannot* ignore the load resistance, the result becomes

$$V_{sum} = V_1 \frac{R_2||R_3||R_4||R_L}{R_1 + R_2||R_3||R_4||R_L} + V_2 \frac{R_1||R_3||R_4||R_L}{R_2 + R_1||R_3||R_4||R_L} + V_3 \frac{R_1||R_2||R_4||R_L}{R_3 + R_1||R_2||R_4||R_L} + V_4 \frac{R_1||R_2||R_3||R_L}{R_4 + R_1||R_2||R_3||R_L}$$

Now, *with* the ideal op-amp and feedback resistor, we have, *independent of the load resistance*,

$$V_{OUT}= -R_F(\frac{V_1}{R_1} +\frac{V_2}{R_2} +\frac{V_3}{R_3} +\frac{V_4}{R_4} )$$

So, let me turn your question around:  *why would you **want** to add voltage without opamp*?

Answer (score 4):

The reason the opamp is used is that it holds the summing node (the one connected to the inverting input) at "virtual ground". This allows the input currents (flowing through R1 ... R4) to be completely independent of each other, creating a true arithmetic sum.

Answer (score 1):

*Strictly speaking*, the circuit you provided is not an adder due to two reasons:

1)  The output in your circuit is of the opposite polarity to the inputs. Thus, an inverter must be added.
2)  For the circuit to be an adder, values of R1, R2, R3 and R4 (and ideally Rf) must be the same.

Please see the amended version of the adder below with formulas explaining operation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPvhDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$${i_1} = {{{V_1}} \over R}, {i_2} = {{{V_2}} \over R}, {i_3} = {{{V_3}} \over R}
$$

$$I = {i_1} + {i_2} + {i_3}$$

$$0 - {V_{out,i}} = I \times R$$
$${V_{out,i}} =  - I \times R =  - ({i_1} + {i_2} + {i_3}) \times R =  - ({V_1} + {V_2} + {V_3})$$

So the output of the first op-amp is an *inverted* sum of the inputs - not exactly what we need.

Adding one more amplifier with gain of -1 and applying the formula for the gain, we get an adder:

$${A_v} = {{{V_{out}}} \over {{V_{out,i}}}} =  - {r \over r} =  - 1,{\rm{ }}{V_{out}} =  - {V_{out,i}}$$
$${V_{out}} = {V_1} + {V_2} + {V_3}$$

Comment: The question is really about why an op amp is needed, though -- not what the transfer function is.

Comment: @Null, I agree. The title of the question is "Operational amplifier adder". I thought, that showing a circuit and calling it an adder, while it is not an adder, strictly speaking, required this remark.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to explain the role of the op-amp in this circuit is by the *virtual ground* concept. Really, it is very important for understanding the role of the op-amp in all op-amp inverting circuits… but it is too difficult for beginners to understand it. They would understand how zero voltage appears at this place if they could imagine two things - first, where the current goes after leaving Rf and second, the fact that the op-amp output is connected in series to the resistor Rf and produces voltage equal to the voltage drop across this resistor. Thus the op-amp output voltage compensates this "undesired" voltage drop. This is a universal principle on which all kinds of op-amp inverting circuits are based (see my [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Voltage_Compensation)).

Tons of explanations of this famous op-amp circuit can be found on the web, which are basically the same.  Here is a qiite different explanation that can make you think more deeply about what exactly the op-amp does here.

Strictly speaking, in total five voltage sources are connected through resistors to the common summing point (five current sources are connected to the summing point each of them consisting of a voltage source and resistor); so the op-amp output can be thought of as another voltage source. From this perspective, it is a kind of "input source"... but we take its voltage as an output quantity. Figuratively speaking, the four input voltage sources "pull" up and down the summing point while the op-amp output voltage "source" restores its initial zero position.